# Bash (Mac): edit file and some if commands

Tags: macos, bash, search, text, edit

i want that my bash script does the following:

It finds a file, for example: hello.txt

It searches for a specific text in the file, for example: hey

If it is found, continue to the next thing,

if it isn't found, write the text on a new line & continue to the next thing.

Can anyone give me the script for this?

EDIT: Also i would like to do this more times in a row, so something time-saving would be great!

Comment: Have you tried writing it yourself? If so, post what you have and describe the problems it gives you. If not, try.

Comment: But i'm a newbie in bash, i did some tutorial, and it helped me, but it doesnt explain how to do this stuff.

Comment: i did work a long time with batch (windows). There i needed sed for this. Are you going to need a special tool too for bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in reply to your comments:

> But i'm a newbie in bash, i did some tutorial, and it helped me, but it doesnt explain how to do this stuff.

Then you probably did the wrong tutorial. The [Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html) at TLDP should be able to help you.

> i did work a long time with batch (windows). There i needed sed for this. Are you going to need a special tool too for bash?

Yes, but they all are standard on most Unix systems (including Mac OS X, I guess).

> can anyone give an answer?

Since I'm in a good mood today...

`grep` is used to search for text in files.

`echo` and redirection (`>` `>>` `<` `|`) work the same in `bash` as they do in Windows' `cmd.exe`, so you probably already know how to use these.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
# The 'if ! grep ...' part is probably the hardest.
if ! grep "hey" "$filename" &> /dev/null; then
    # "hey" was not found - use 'echo' to add it
fi
...
```

The rest you should figure out yourself.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Yeah, i already understand 'echo hey >>filename'